# Usar os valores de uma variável array de um procedimento na rotina principal do algoritmo

Tags: delphi, procedure, pascal

```
program nome_jogadores_futebol_basquete_volei;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

procedure futebol;
  var
    i: integer;
    jogador: array[1..11] of string;
  begin
    for i := 1 to 11 do
      begin
        writeln('Digite o nome do jogador ', i);
        readln(jogador[i]);
      end;
  end;
procedure basquete;
  var
    i: integer;
    jogador: array[1..5] of string;
  begin
    for i := 1 to 5 do
      begin
        writeln('Digite o nome do jogador ', i);
        readln(jogador[i]);
      end;
  end;
procedure volei;
  var
    i: integer;
    jogador: array[1..6] of string;
  begin
    for i := 1 to 6 do
      begin
        writeln('Digite o nome do jogador ', i);
        readln(jogador[i]);
      end;
  end;
var
  esporte, verificar: char;
  i: integer;
begin
  writeln('Digite o esporte que voce joga([f - futebol][b - basquete][v - volei])');
  readln(esporte);
  if esporte = 'f' then
    begin
      futebol;
    end
  else if esporte = 'b' then
    begin
      basquete;
    end
  else if esporte = 'v' then
    begin
      volei;
    end;
  writeln('Deseja verificar o nome dos jogadores(s/n)');
  readln(verificar);
  while verificar = 's' do
    begin
      writeln('Digite o numero do jogador');
      readln(i);
      writeln('Nome do jogador ', i, ': ', jogador[i]);
      writeln('Deseja verificar outro jogador(s/n)');
      readln(verificar);
    end;
  readln;
end.
```

Gostaria de usar os valores da variável `jogador` que se encontra em um procedimento, na rotina principal do algoritmo.

Comment: Não possível acessar essa variável desta forma, se você tiver que utilizar `procedure` realmente, terá que colocar a variável `jogador` no escopo global. Ou se puder altera para `function` poderá retornar a lista de nomes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você cria uma variável dentro de um um método/função/procedimento, essa variável só pode ser acessada dentro do próprio escopo, sendo assim, você não consegue acessar a variável da função 1 estando na função 2 a não ser que seja um retorno ou parâmetro passado por referência.

Uma outra forma de fazer o que você precisa é utilizar uma variável global, não acho que seja a melhor forma, mas atende e também é mais fácil de compreender para quem esta iniciando.

Para se criar uma variável global também utilizamos a seção `var`, mas, logo abaixo da seção `uses`:

```
uses
  SysUtils;

var
  jogadores: ?????
```

> Mas aqui entra uma dúvida: Qual deverá ser o tipo da variável
>   `jogadores`? Já que para futebol teremos 11, basquete 5 e vôlei 6.

O macete é: não precisamos definir o tamanho de um `array` na declaração, podemos defini-lo futuramente. Para isso basta definir como um `array` de `string`:

```
uses
  SysUtils;

var
  jogadores: Array of String;
```

Agora que temos a variável global para armazenarmos os jogadores, vamos criar os métodos responsáveis por definir o tamanho do `array` e solicitar os nomes para serem armazenados.

> Mas como vamos definir o tamanho do `array` durante a execução do
>   programa?

Simples, iremos utilizar a função [SetLength](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=setlength). Essa função serve tanto para definir o tamanho de uma `string` como o tamanho de um `array`. No nosso caso, iremos definir o tamanho de um `array`, o primeiro parâmetro é a variável que será redimensionada e o segundo é o novo tamanho da variável:

```
uses
  SysUtils;

var
  jogadores: Array of String;

procedure futebol;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(jogadores, 11);
  for i := 1 to 11 do
    begin
      writeln('Digite o nome do jogador ', i);
      readln(jogadores[i - 1]);
    end;
end;

procedure basquete;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(jogadores, 5);
  for i := 1 to 5 do
    begin
      writeln('Digite o nome do jogador ', i);
      readln(jogadores[i - 1]);
    end;
end;

procedure volei;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(jogadores, 6);
  for i := 1 to 6 do
    begin
      writeln('Digite o nome do jogador ', i);
      readln(jogadores[i - 1]);
    end;
end;
```

> Observe que dessa forma o primeiro item do `array` sempre será a
>   posição `0`, por isso quando estamos atribuindo precisamos subtrair 1
>   do número que o usuário esta vendo.

Agora é só implementar o processo que você já fez, apenas mudando para `jogadores` os lugares que estão como `jogador`:

```
uses
  SysUtils;

var
  jogadores: Array of String;

procedure futebol;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(jogadores, 11);
  for i := 1 to 11 do
    begin
      writeln('Digite o nome do jogador ', i);
      readln(jogadores[i - 1]);
    end;
end;

procedure basquete;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(jogadores, 5);
  for i := 1 to 5 do
    begin
      writeln('Digite o nome do jogador ', i);
      readln(jogadores[i - 1]);
    end;
end;

procedure volei;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(jogadores, 6);
  for i := 1 to 6 do
    begin
      writeln('Digite o nome do jogador ', i);
      readln(jogadores[i - 1]);
    end;
end;

var
  esporte, verificar: char;
  i: integer;
begin
  writeln('Digite o esporte que voce joga([f - futebol][b - basquete][v - volei])');
  readln(esporte);
  if esporte = 'f' then
    begin
      futebol;
    end
  else if esporte = 'b' then
    begin
      basquete;
    end
  else if esporte = 'v' then
    begin
      volei;
    end;
  writeln('Deseja verificar o nome dos jogadores(s/n)');
  readln(verificar);
  while verificar = 's' do
    begin
      writeln('Digite o numero do jogador');
      readln(i);
      writeln('Nome do jogador ', i, ': ', jogadores[i - 1]);
      writeln('Deseja verificar outro jogador(s/n)');
      readln(verificar);
    end;
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Muito obrigado esclareceu muito bem minhas duvidas, gostaria de saber se teria algum problema usar a variavel jogador com o array estipulado do 1..11 assim mesmo se fosse volei ou basquete a variavel cobre a quantidade dos jogadores, isso em vez de usar a função SetLength.

Comment: Vai dar certo. Porém você estará utilizando mais espaço da memória sem necessidade.